# Write a shell script to replace phone number from a file

Tags: linux, unix, shell, shell-script

I have a file called test.txt and the content of this file is:

```
cat test.txt

abc,123456,india
dfg,78910,china
abc,893948,japan
abc,892389,australia
```

I tried using the below shell script, but I'm unable replace it:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(cat /tmp/file.txt)
do
i=$(echo $line|grep XYZ |awk -F, '{print $2}')
while ( $i )
do
sed -i 's/$i/00070/g';
done


done
```

So I want a shell script to replace all abc's phone number to 00070 or any unique number.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a shell **script**. A single call to sed is enough:

```
sed -i -r 's/abc,[0-9]+,/abc,00000,/' <yourfile>
```

Sed will iterate the file and execute the replace instruction on each line (where the first member matches something of course). It is assumed that the phone numbers are just a sequence of digits (no dots, plus signs, etc...).

With a script, you don't need grep/sed either, you just split the line on commas, and generate a new line with the parts you extracted:

```
IFS=','; while read name phone country; do [[ $name == 'abc' ]] && phone="0000"; echo "$name,$phone,$country" ; done < Test.txt >Filtered.txt
```

Edit: missed the bit about only the "abc" lines. Fixed

Comment: Could you tell me what if our input is a file in the script

Comment: I tried sed though and even its not working
sed -i -r 's/abc,,/abc,0070,/' mytest.txt

Comment: Not working how (what are the results)? And this isn't the command I gave you...

Comment: So please do let me know answer according to my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace a entire content of a file maybe a better solution than loop line by line is the use of the command sed. try this `sed -i 's|abc,.*,|abc,0700,|g' test.txt`

Comment: Actually your command is removing country part from the file

Comment: No, this command works (on the "abc" lines). What exact command did you use?

Comment: The command does exactly what you asked, change the number of the telephone at lines begging with `abc`. What command did you use?